# Display trimmed version of the_post()

Tags: query-posts

I am using the following code to display pages on one page and would like to trim the content of each page on this display to 50 words and include images that are attached to the page.  How do I go about doing this?

```
  $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_parent' => '6',
            'order'=> 'DESC'

            );
            query_posts($args);
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

Comment: What does "attached to the page" mean? Are the image tags embedded in the post body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, never use query_posts, use WP_Query instead.
To show 50 carachters of each one of the pages:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => '6',
        'order'=> 'DESC'    
        );
$pages_returned = new WP_Query($args);
        while ( $pages_returned->have_posts()): $pages_returned->the_post(); ?>

<div class="page-excerpt">
     <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
     <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Now for your 50 chars limit, on your functions.php add

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 50;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

That should be it.

Answer (score 1):

First, please don't use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Create a new `WP_Query` object.

> Note: This function isn't meant to be used by plugins or themes. As
>   explained later, there are better, more performant options to alter
>   the main query. Double Note: query_posts() is overly simplistic and
>   problematic way to modify main query of a page by replacing it with
>   new instance of the query. It is inefficient (re-runs SQL queries) and
>   will outright fail in some circumstances (especially often when
>   dealing with posts pagination). Any modern WP code should use more
>   reliable methods, like making use of pre_get_posts hook, for this
>   purpose. TL;DR don't use query_posts() ever;

Then, something like this should work:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => '6',
        'order'=> 'DESC'

        );
$qry = new WP_Query($args);
        while ( $qry->have_posts() ) {
            $qry->the_post(); 
            the_excerpt();
        }
```

You could also use [`wp_trim_words`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words) with `$post->post_content`.

Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: How would I have this also include the media that's in the page? And not strip the html.

Comment: That wasn't part of the original question, and the answer depends on how the "media" is included in the post. That is, whether it is a featured image, embedded in the post body, part of a meta field, etc.

Comment: Ok- I edited the question.